# RDLC: change Now format

Tags: rdlc

I have a Problem with a RDLC, 
if I see the Now value before Render, it is in DE format 
(**03.11.2015 12:07:16**), 
when I show the Now Value after .render is **11/3/2015 11:56:44 AM**
why change settings????

Answer (score 0):

Report Language has to be set.

```
<Report>
   ...
   <Language>=User!Language</Language>
</Report>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is another way from inside the Visual studio editor.

When you select the field in the property windows there is the language setting, from the combo box you can choose the language that you want or set a parameter that id passed to the report, as you can see from the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

right click on the box containing the date , then select option "Expression" finally you must put something like:

**=CDate(Parameters!dateStart.Value).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss")**

"Parameters!dateStart.Value" change it to your data source
finally you click on **"accept"**

*The reason for the change is because the server format , Where is the application , has a regional configuration*